Auto typewriter html content to corresponding widget
Below mentioned the html content

"<ol><li><strong>Personalized Gift</strong>: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests. &nbsp;</li>    <li><strong>Surprise Party</strong>: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.&nbsp;</li>    <li><strong> Romantic Dinner</strong>: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.</li></ol>"

I need to convert above to this below i mentioned

Personalized Gift: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests.   Surprise Party: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.   Romantic Dinner: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.

with auto typewriter functionality
I already used some plugins to render htlm to text with auto typewrite , this kind of plugins but not available in flutter and also used htlm render plugins and typewrite plugins but they won't work to together
How to achieve render html content , text as widget with auto typewriter ?

Please add enough code inside the question to create a [mre]. Keep in mind that asking recommendations on libraries, tutorials, etc. is off-topic on SO - [ask]

no plugins available to handle that kind of functionality , need to write custom codes ,
we have to generate custom typewriter animation effects
used one plugin : flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.15.0 for render Html to widget
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_new_v3_2_2/textwidgetdemo.dart';
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var demoList = [
    {
      "question": "1 Planing",
      "ans":
          "<ol><li><strong>Personalized Gift</strong>: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests. &nbsp;</li>    <li><strong>Surprise Party</strong>: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.&nbsp;</li>    <li><strong> Romantic Dinner</strong>: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.</li></ol>"
    },
    {
      "question": "2 Planing",
      "ans":
          "<ol><li><strong>Personalized Gift</strong>: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests. &nbsp;</li>    <li><strong>Surprise Party</strong>: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.&nbsp;</li>    <li><strong> Romantic Dinner</strong>: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.</li></ol>"
    },
    {
      "question": "3 Planing",
      "ans":
          "<ol><li><strong>Personalized Gift</strong>: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests. &nbsp;</li>    <li><strong>Surprise Party</strong>: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.&nbsp;</li>    <li><strong> Romantic Dinner</strong>: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.</li></ol>"
    },
    {
      "question": "4 Planing",
      "ans":
          "<ol><li><strong>Personalized Gift</strong>: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests. &nbsp;</li>    <li><strong>Surprise Party</strong>: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.&nbsp;</li>    <li><strong> Romantic Dinner</strong>: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.</li></ol>"
    },
    {
      "question": "5 Planing",
      "ans":
          "<ol><li><strong>Personalized Gift</strong>: Consider giving her a thoughtful and personalized gift that shows how much you know and appreciate her. It could be a piece of jewelry, a custom-made item, or something related to her hobbies or interests. &nbsp;</li>    <li><strong>Surprise Party</strong>: Organize a surprise party with close friends and family. Make sure to incorporate her favorite colors, themes, and activities into the party. You could also arrange for a live band, DJ, or hire a professional photographer to capture all the special moments.&nbsp;</li>    <li><strong> Romantic Dinner</strong>: Treat her to a romantic dinner at her favorite restaurant or plan a cozy dinner at home. Cook her favorite meal yourself or order from her preferred restaurant. Set the mood with candles, soft music, and maybe even a bottle of champagne or wine.</li></ol>"
    }
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: demoList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var item = demoList[index];
                return TextWidetDemo(
                  qtn: item["question"],
                  ans: item["ans"],
                  indexOftext: index,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

textwidgetdemo.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';

class TextWidetDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? qtn;
  final String? ans;
  final int? indexOftext;
  final Duration duration;

  const TextWidetDemo(
      {super.key,
      this.ans,
      this.qtn,
      this.indexOftext,
      this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 50)});

  @override
  State<TextWidetDemo> createState() => _TextWidetDemoState();
}

class _TextWidetDemoState extends State<TextWidetDemo> {
  String _displayedText = "";
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  Timer? _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.indexOftext == 0) {
      _startTyping();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startTyping() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(widget.duration, (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_currentIndex < widget.ans!.length) {
          _displayedText += widget.ans![_currentIndex];
          _currentIndex++;
        } else {
          _timer?.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(
            widget.qtn!,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: widget.indexOftext == 0
                ? HtmlWidget(
                    _displayedText,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  )
                : HtmlWidget(
                    widget.ans!,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ))
      ],
    );
  }
}

This way you can achieve it
